# Number of labelled spanning trees in the following graph.

Tags: graph-theory, trees, adjacency-matrix

[image]

Hi, I have this question in one of my assignments. Normally I would use an adjacency matrix (a very big one) to solve these kinds of questions but the hint makes me believe the professor wants me to solve this in a different way. I see no mention in the lectures of why cycles of length 4 have any significance in counting the number of spanning trees so I'm wondering if anyone can help me out with maybe a theorem or lemma that I'm missing? I'm not looking for the answer, just the tools to each the answer because right now I am at a loss. The hint is throwing me off a lot.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: The picture is a bit blurry. The hint says "Consider 5 cases depending on how many edges of the cycle of length 4 you keep."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll expand on the hint a bit.

Suppose that you remove all $4$ edges of the $4$-cycle. What’s left is a $16$-cycle; how many labelled spanning trees does it have?

Now suppose that you remove only $3$ of those $4$ edges: you have a $5$-cycle and a $13$-cycle that share one edge. How many more edges must you remove to get a spanning tree? How many labelled spanning trees can you get in this case?

There are three more cases, and they’re a bit harder, but the principle is the same for all of them: you have to remove just enough edges to break every cycle.

Comment: So just to make sure I'm understanding it right, since a spanning tree should have n-1 edges with n vertices and no cycles, that first case would be 16 spanning trees (as I can remove any of the 16 edges), and the second case would be 5*13, as I must remove two edges, one from the 13-cycle and one from the 5-cycle. Don't have to tell me if I'm right or wrong just if my logic is correct.

Edit: 5*13*4 for the second case, as the edge I keep in the 4-cycle could be any of them.

Comment: @A.Boy: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was one of those cases where I think I may have done better without the hint haha.

Comment: @A.Boy: You’re welcome.